# brace editor initialValue setup

Tags: javascript, npm

I am using [brace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brace) to show suggestions as i type a SQL query,
but when the page first renders I want it to show an initialQuery

I want to initialize the editor div with a query somewhere here-

```
this.editor = ace.edit("editor");
    this.editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");

    const varIndex = window.variables.findIndex((item) => item.varName === this.newVar.varName);
    if (varIndex !== -1) {
      this.editor.setOption("placeholder", window.variables[varIndex].sqlQuery);
    } else {
      this.editor.setOption("placeholder", "Enter your SQL query here...");
    }
```

right now I'm using placeholder but I want the query to be editable and persist when user starts typing